# Springjdbc template select query execution is taking long time

Tags: spring, select, jdbc

i am executing one select query using Springjdbc template and it is returning nearly 1000 ids as a set. but it is taking 10 mins time for execution using Spring jdbc template.
but in Toad, same query is executing with in seconds.

can any one pls help me regarding this?

and i am using below code:

```
return (HashSet)this.jdbcTemplate.query(
   (String) sqlMap.get("SQL_NRChargePromoApIDList"), new Object[] {  }, new DataMapperAPID());

public Object mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
        HashSet compList = new HashSet();        
        compList.add(rs.getString("ap_id"));
        while(rs.next()){
            compList.add(rs.getString("ap_id"));
        }
        return compList;
      }
```

Comment: can any one post the answer pls

Comment: Not really enough info to go on. Did you profile the Java app to see where time is being taken up?

Comment: return (HashSet)this.jdbcTemplate.query( (String) sqlMap.get("SQL_NRChargePromoApIDList"), new Object[] { }, new DataMapperAPID()); thisstatement is taking 10 minutes time even i added hard coded values in query, but same query is executing Toad with in seconds .

Comment: Yeah, we already see the call you're making. Did you profile the Java app to see *where* the time is being taken up?

Comment: tame is taking only to execute this "SQL_NRChargePromoApIDList" query only

Comment: I don't think you're getting the point. Executing a stored proc will still involve other Spring methods, object instantiation, communication with the DB, etc.

Comment: So, what does the `SQL_NRChargePromoApIDList` query look like? And the `DataMapperAPID` class? This question is missing very much pertinent information.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to call rs.next() as the whole point of the RowMapper that you pass in to [JdbcTemplate.query()](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#query%28org.springframework.jdbc.core.PreparedStatementCreator,%20org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper%29) is that it will automatically iterate across all the rows in the resultset and insert the mapped object into a list, which it will then return. the row mapper should simply extract the app_id and then return it. Upon completion, you will get back a List.